# How to use dwExtraInfo with SendInput

Tags: c, winapi, mouseevent, user-data, sendinput

I'm using `::SendInput` to send a mouse click event:

```
void LeftDown (LONG x_cord, LONG y_cord)
{  
    INPUT    Input={0};
    // left down 
    Input.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
    Input.mi.dwFlags  = MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN;
    Input.mi.dx = x_cord;
    Input.mi.dy = y_cord;
    Input.mi.dwExtraInfo = 0x12345;   //Is this how to use it?
    ::SendInput(1,&Input,sizeof(INPUT));
}
```

I want to set the `dwExtraInfo` to some self defined value and extract it in the `WndProc` at the target application. Then (for example) I will ignore that click if the `dwExtraInfo` is set to some specific value:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK OSRWindow::WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{ 
    if(message == WM_LBUTTONDOWN)
    {          
        if(GetMessageExtraInfo() == 0x12345)     //Is this how to use it?
            //ignore
        else
            //do something
    }
}
```

Is this naive way is the proper way to use `dwExtraInfo` or is there a better practice? Thanks!

Comment: This invariably fails the "what if two programs do this" sanity test.

Comment: @HansPassant What do you mean?

Comment: If the machine is running another program that also injecting input and using dwExtraInfo to pass info then your hook just can't tell anymore what it is supposed to mean.  This is more common than you might think btw, google 0xFF515700 to see what kind of trouble is looming.  So it probably works just fine on your machine but you'll have no idea what can happen on another.

Comment: Expanding on Hans Passant's comment, using *dwExtraInfo* is never safe when used with standard Windows messages. Passing information through *dwExtraInfo* with custom control messages (`WM_USER+x`) or application private messages (`WM_APP+x`) should be safe, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646273.aspx) says:

> **dwExtraInfo**
>
> An additional value associated with the mouse event. An application calls GetMessageExtraInfo to obtain this extra information.

So yes, use it just as you have shown it in your question.